# Why immutable singleton has no global state?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, immutability

In an article called [Root Cause of Singletons](https://testing.googleblog.com/2008/08/root-cause-of-singletons.html) writed by Miško Hevery:

> Now, there is one kind of Singleton which is OK. That is a singleton where all of the reachable objects are immutable. If all objects are immutable than Singleton has no global state, as everything is constant.

A singleton always has global state, because all of the design patterns of singleton expose a global reference to the single instance.

But why immutable singleton has no global state?

Comment: because if all the objects reachable by the singleton are immutable, the singleton as a whole is unchanging reference data. other singletons are evil because of the problems of shared state. but because this singleton is unchanging, the problems of shared state can't arise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of this kind of Singleton that the author describes as just a static, constant object.

The singleton pattern does not necessarily guarantee immutability. So imagine that you have a Singleton that is used by many other modules/components/objects in your code and its state changes. This could arguably lead to unexpected behavior. Object A leaves the singleton in a state A, but nothing guarantees that the singleton's state won't become B after a while.

I think this is what the author tries to outline here. Example singletons of this kind are configuration objects, or static Maps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Since immutable object cannot be reused and are just a use and throw object, improper usage may lead to large amount of garbage, thereby lowering the performance of application.

Singleton pattern is a software design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to one object. This is useful when exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system.

A singleton must be thread-safe if used in multiple threads; 
immutable objects is also thread-safe but they are inherently thread-safe.
```